# How do I stop a javascript from executing using confirm?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I need help with getting the prevention of a button blick to work if the user does not click yes on the confirmation window, this worked well for submits, but it doesn't seem to have any effect when there is a javascript that runs when the button is clicked.

the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteResource btn btn-link NoBorder NoBackGround" data-id="@resource.Id" data-url="@Url.Action("DeleteResource")" data-confirm="are you sure?" />
```

the javascript:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('[data-confirm]').click(function (e) {
            if (!confirm(jQuery(this).attr("data-confirm"))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.deleteResource').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var param = { id: id }
        $.post(url, param, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert("Kunde inte utföra åtgärden.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: Did you mean `jQuery('.deleteResource').click(function() {`?

Comment: well I was hoping for that to not happen if the confirm wasn't hmm. clicked yes

Comment: my problem is that the stuff gets deleted regardless

Comment: What is the element with `class="deleteTraffic"`? Its not clear what your trying to do. Best guess is you want the confirm on the element with `class="deleteTraffic"`.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, I copied the wrong function from the js file. I'll edit the post

Comment: Just combine the 2 as per the answer by Tsar. But your ajax call makes no sense. Why in the world would you make an ajax call and then do a `location.reload();` - your negating the whole purpose of making an ajax call. I suspect what you really want to do is just remove some elements from the DOM

Comment: The goal was to remove the things from the database, not just the DOM

Comment: It will remove them from the database - that's what your controllers `DeleteResource()` method will do. Then if its successful, you remove the item from the DOM, otherwise display an error message. Not sure who down-vote Tsar's answer, but its correct (just remove your first javascript function)

Comment: I would like that. how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116441/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-inifus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to prevent other handlers on the same element from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.deleteResource').click(function() {
        if (confirm(jQuery(this).attr("data-confirm"))) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            var param = { id: id }
            $.post(url, param, function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert("Kunde inte utföra åtgärden.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I considered this, but wouldn't that make the confirm window pop up twice?

Comment: this is all you require, delete the other function

Comment: the problem is that I have an input of type submit that does not run javascript, I can't prevent that from happening if I don't have the other function there.